# Ant walking on an icosahedron

Tags: probability

(Source: My Own Question. Influenced by 2018 AIME #10)

Let's say we have a regular icosahedron. Say a bug starts on one vertex. Say the bug travels on vertices, going to an adjacent vertex each turn. With 6 turns, what's the probability that the bug ends up on its starting point

I don't have a darn idea how to do this problem. Could anyone help.

Comment: Draw Markov chain, establish transition matrix $P$, Calculate $P^6$ and multiply it by appropriate initial vector and look at the initial state entry.

Comment: You should build the graph's adjacency-probability matrix $A$ calculate $A^6$ and look at the diagonal.

Comment: The total number of walks with $n$ steps is $4^n$. Those that return to the start are in https://oeis.org/A054881 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are four different classes of vertices: the initial vertex, its neighbours, their neighbours, and the opposite vertex. The matrix of transition probabilities (with the classes in that order) is

$$
\frac15\pmatrix{0&1&0&0\\5&2&2&0\\0&2&2&5\\0&0&1&0}\;.
$$

This matrix happens to have [a reasonably simple eigensystem](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eigendecomposition%20%7B%7B0,1,0,0%7D,%7B5,2,2,0%7D,%7B0,2,2,5%7D,%7B0,0,1,0%7D%7D&dataset=). The initial state decomposes as

$$
\pmatrix{1\\0\\0\\0}=\frac1{12}\left(\pmatrix{1\\5\\5\\1}+3\pmatrix{1\\\sqrt5\\-\sqrt5\\-1}+3\pmatrix{1\\-\sqrt5\\\sqrt5\\-1}+5\pmatrix{1\\-1\\-1\\1}\right)
$$

with eigenvalues $5^0$, $5^{-\frac12}$,$-5^{-\frac12}$ and $5^{-1}$, respectively. Thus, after $6$ steps, the components are multiplied by $5^0$, $5^{-3}$, $5^{-3}$ and $5^{-6}$, respectively, and the resulting distribution is

$$
5^{-5}\pmatrix{273\\1302\\1302\\248\\}\;.
$$

Thus, the probability to return to the starting point is $\frac{273}{3125}=\frac1{12}+\frac{151}{37500}\approx\frac1{12}+0.004$.

Comment: Could you explain why you did what you did with the eigenvalues? I'm not too well versed in matrices.

Comment: @APiercingArrow: I used Wolfram|Alpha to find the eigenvectors and eigenvalues (see the link). The eigenvectors turned out to be regular enough that I could see without computation how the initial state can be decomposed into them (second equation). Once you've decomposed a vector into the eigenvectors of a matrix, multiplying it by the matrix becomes easy: Each eigenvector is multiplied by the corresponding eigenvalue. Since we need to apply the transition matrix six times (for six ant steps), I multiplied each eigenvector with the sixth power of its eigenvalue.

Comment: You might want to check out [eigendecomposition of a matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix) at Wikipedia, especially [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Functional_calculus).

Comment: The three eigenvectors that represent deviations from the uniform distribution have eigenvalues below $1$ and decay with each step. What remains in the long run is the first eigenvector, $\frac1{12}(1,5,5,1)^\top$, which corresponds to eigenvalue $1$ and represents the uniform distribution. If I hadn't combined two groups of $5$ equivalent vertices into classes to simplify the computation, this would be a constant vector of length $12$.

Answer (score 0):

Denote $v_i$ the vertices, $\mathbf{A}$ the adjacency matrix of the corresponding graph and $\mathbf{A}^6=(b_{ij}).$ 
Recall that $b_{ij}$ is the number of paths of length $6$ from $v_i$ to $v_j$.

The probability to return to $v_i$ if the ant started in this same vertex, is $$p_i=\frac{b_{ii}}{\sum_{j=1}^{12}b_{ij}}.$$